# NextJS React Context Sharing Across Libraries

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have an App Package(APP) which is a Nextjs package. I'm using a custom library(LIB) inside this package.

APP package.json

```
 'LIB':'some github package'
```

I'm trying to have a react context declared in LIB and used both on LIB and APP.

MainContext.js inside LIB

```
export const MainContext = createContext({
  all: 'default value',
  setAll: () => {},
});
```

_app.js inside APP

```
import { MainContext } from 'LIB'
....
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const [all, setAll] = useState({})
       
    return (
            <MainContext.Provider value={{ all, setAll }}>
            .....
            </MainContext.Provider>
          );
}
```

However, I'm facing issues such as `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Provider')`

I tried log the context many times, and it does exist and it is imported correctly, still, I'm stuck with errors that Provider is undefined.

At some point, I logged the provider and it existed then it disappears. I'm pretty sure something is wrong there but I can not find it.